# Activating and de-activating record selectors

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to understand how to create a button that allows the activation and deactivation of record selector BUT upon doing so, the headings in the form/page header move with the records as well to avoid that annoying disalignment between the column labels on the form header and the data in the body of the form.

```
    Me.RecordSelectors = True
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'selectort' ... is that 'select / sort'? Are you trying to hide a column on a form/report? Can you give an example of why they become misaligned?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in your button (but you can add code to exclude certain controls if needed):

```
Private Sub cmdToggleRS_Click()
Dim ctl     As Control
If Me.RecordSelectors = True Then
    Me.RecordSelectors = False
    For Each ctl In Me.Section("FormHeader").Controls
        If ctl.Name <> "SkipThis" Then
            ctl.LeftPadding = ctl.LeftPadding - 20
        End If
    Next ctl
Else
    Me.RecordSelectors = True
    For Each ctl In Me.Section("FormHeader").Controls
        If ctl.Name <> "SkipThis" Then
            ctl.LeftPadding = ctl.LeftPadding + 20
        End If
    Next ctl
End If
End Sub
```